# how to re-write htaccess file, to change URL

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

I am trying to convert the actual `URL` to user friendly there is dynamic menu, when user click on page the original `URL` becomes like [this](http://example.com/website/public)

I want to change it to [this](http://example.com)

I have use these code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# map neat URL to internal URL...
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [L,R=301]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's just this address then:

```
RewriteRule ^website/public / [L]
```

If all adresses started with website/public then:

```
RewriteRule ^website/public/(.*) $1 [L]
```